# cut the first and last element in CSV

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, csv

I have an array in a CSV file as

```
input.csv
"{1,2,3,4}"
"{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}"
"{34,6,7,89}"
```

I want to get the first and the last element of this CSV file as another CSV file

```
output.csv
    1,4
    1,9
    34,89
```

I tried with

```
  cut -d , -f1 -- complement input.csv > output.csv
```

I know this works for normal CSV.But here I have curly braces and ""
 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way with `sed`

```
$ sed -r 's/"\{([0-9]+,).*,([0-9]+)\}"/\1\2/' input
1,4
1,9
34,89
```

#### Notes

- `-r` use ERE
- `\}` literal `{`
- `([0-9]+,)` save some digits followed by a comma for later
- `\1\2` back reference to saved patterns

(your output is indented, - so maybe you want `/   \1\2/` or `/\t\1\2/` in the replacement - adjust as you like)

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
awk -F"[}{,]" '{print $2, $(NF-1)}' OFS=,  file
```

You can use the curly braces also as delimiters and hence the elements can be accessed directly.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/,.*,/,/' -e 's/[^0-9,]//g' file
```

The first `s` command replaces everything between the first and last comma with a comma, effectively eliminating all content in between.

The second `s` command removes all characters that are not a digit or a comma.

Answer (score 1):

this code will work for you

```
cat input.csv|sed 's/\"//g'|sed 's/{//g'|sed 's/}//g'|awk -F "," '{print $1,",",$NF}'|tr -d " " > output.csv
```

`sed 's/\"//g'` will eliminate the ", 
`sed 's/{//g'|sed 's/}//g'` will eliminate the braces,
`awk -F "," '{print $1,",",$NF}'` will give you this result

```
1 , 4
1 , 9
34 , 89
```

and `tr -d " "` will eliminate the spaces in the output

Comment: you know sed 1) can use multiple susbstitute 2) can have a file of its own ?

Comment: yes by using the -e option or the ; but i want to make it simple

Answer (score -1):

```
sed -r "s/(\"|\{|\})//g" input.csv|awk -F, '{print $1","$NF}'
```